# Updating Swing GUI with while loop and delay

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, event-dispatch-thread, swingutilities

I have a while loop that is supposed to update the program data and the GUI, but the GUI part freezes until the while loop is done executing.

Here is my code:

```
while(game.getCompTotal() < 17) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2500);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    game.compHit();           // Program data update

    updateCardPanels();       // GUI update -- Does not update until the while loop finishes.

    if(game.checkCompBust()){
        if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Dealer Busted.  Play again?") == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            init();           // Reset
        }   
    }
}
```

I have tried using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` and a `Swing Timer` but I do not really get how `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` works or how to use a `Swing Timer` on the EDT.  My question is how can I have the GUI update at the same time as the program data in the while loop?

Here is my attempted `invokeLater()` code:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Timer t = new Timer(100, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                updateCardPanels();
            }
        });
        t.setInitialDelay(0);
        t.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: A Swing `Timer` can be used as a pseudo loop, on each "tick" of the `Timer`, you update some kind of state variable, determine if the exit condition has been achieved or not and update the remaining state as you normally would (in a loop) otherwise

Comment: OK I think I have that working.  Now I have a different problem:  How can I wait for the `Timer` to finish before continuing through the program?

Comment: Have the `Timer` call a method after it's finished (ie the exit condition is met)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looks like your while loop is on EDT and thats why it freezes GUI while it is executing. **Never call `Thread.sleep` on EDT.**
2. All `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` does is puts the `Runnable` on a queue so that EDT would run it at some point in time. The `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` should be run from a non EDT thread. Starting Swing Timer with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is not required. You can start it directly from EDT.
3. Swing timer uses a separate thread that runs and periodically calls specified `ActionListener` on EDT thread.

You can replace the `while` loop with swing timer (lets say with 1sec interval) and check `game.getCompTotal() < 17` condition inside its `actionPerformed` call.